# Resources about hardware usability

Tags: usability, resources

I am a user experience researcher working primary on websites. I am considering shifting to the hardware domain and I am wondering what kind of general reference resources are out there about hardware usability. By hardware I mean any physical products like computer, handheld devices, webcam, mouse, keyboard, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware usability is covered well by the domain of human factors engineering (a.k.a., engineering psychology, ergonomics). A textbook in that area is a great way to get background (e.g., Christopher Wicken’s Engineering Psychology and Human Performance). There’s probably a book on human factors specifically emphasizing consumer electronics. Lord knows [they need it](http://www.zuschlogin.com/?p=39).

There also various US government standards and guidelines that emphasize usable hardware, such as:

- [MIL-STD 1472](http://www.public.navy.mil/navsafecen/Documents/acquisition/MILSTD1472F.pdf) DOD Design Criteria Standard: Human Engineering
- MIL-HDBK 759 DOD Handbook for Human Engineering Design Guidelines
- [DOT/FAA/CT-96/1](http://hf.tc.faa.gov/hfds/) FAA Human Factors Design Guide

These were written for high-risk applications, but they apply just as well to consumer electronics.